# How to get coordinates of cursor from text area in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to get position of cursor(coordinates x,y) from textarea on input change(keyboard event), i cannot use click event as well, i want you only on change event or on blur or on keyup events.

```
        <textarea name="text" [(ngModel)]="model" (keyup)="onChange($event)"  cols="75" rows="10">
         </textarea>

  onChange(event:any){
    console.log(event.clientx)
   }
```

By using jquery i was able to get but i want to do it on angular.My actual requirement is when some text is matched then i want to display some popup menu in particular position so how i can  get coordinates of cursor on input change?

Any help is greatly appreciated Thank you!

Comment: @kabanus he/she is not searching for the position of a mouseclick ...

Comment: yes i'm not looking for mouseclick, i'm looking for change event that should fire on change of text.